# How to change background color of a row on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have html table and also had some rows with checkbox. Onselction of checkbox i want to higlight that row with some background color.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='chkOrgRow' name='chkOrgRow' onclick='selectOrgChildRec(this)' />
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>3/14/2015 </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>1412</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1235</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>3/14/2015 12:13:56 PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='chkOrgRow' name='chkOrgRow' onclick='selectOrgChildRec(this)' />
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>3/14/2015 </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>1412</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1235</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>3/14/2015 12:13:56 PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='chkOrgRow' name='chkOrgRow' onclick='selectOrgChildRec(this)' />
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>3/14/2015 </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>1412</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1235</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>3/14/2015 12:13:56 PM</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The `id` attribute in HTML must be unique.

Answer (score 4):

1. `id` should be **unique**
2. Don't use inline event handlers
3. Don't use inline styles, use CSS classes

```js
$('input[name="chkOrgRow"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('yellow', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='chkOrgRow' />
    </td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>3/14/2015</td>
    <td>78</td>
    <td>1412</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1235</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>R</td>
    <td>3/14/2015 12:13:56 PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='chkOrgRow' />
    </td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>3/14/2015</td>
    <td>78</td>
    <td>1412</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1235</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>R</td>
    <td>3/14/2015 12:13:56 PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='chkOrgRow' />
    </td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>3/14/2015</td>
    <td>78</td>
    <td>1412</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1235</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>R</td>
    <td>3/14/2015 12:13:56 PM</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("[name='chkOrgRow']").change(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('ColorChange');
});
```

```css
.ColorChange{
  background-color: #CCFFCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='chkOrgRow' />
    </td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>3/14/2015</td>
    <td>78</td>
    <td>1412</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1235</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>R</td>
    <td>3/14/2015 12:13:56 PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='chkOrgRow' />
    </td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>3/14/2015</td>
    <td>78</td>
    <td>1412</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1235</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>R</td>
    <td>3/14/2015 12:13:56 PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='chkOrgRow' />
    </td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>3/14/2015</td>
    <td>78</td>
    <td>1412</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1235</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>R</td>
    <td>3/14/2015 12:13:56 PM</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function which will check the checkbox is checked and then change it's color if it was checked.

```
function selectOrgChildRec(checkBox){  
   if(checkBox.checked==true){
      checkbox.parentNode.background='red';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If at all you are using `inline` function then you can just do it with one line with `css` class toggled as below:

```
function selectOrgChildRec(ctrl){
    $(ctrl).closest('tr').toggleClass('active');
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/w5t75d7o/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate IDs for elements. IDs should be always unique. You can rather use same classname tham ID. I would also recommend you to attach the event using jquery rather than inline events:

```
$('input[name="chkOrgRow"]').on('change', function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', $(this).is(':checked') ? 'yellow': '');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0acg9my9/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $("input[type=checkbox]").on('change',function(){
     if($(this).prop('checked')) 
     {
         $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', '#a52a2a');
     }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table cellpadding="15em" cellspacing="5em" border="2px">
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>dbc</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>pqr</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>lbc</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```