# Change color of row when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I''ve been trying to change the color of the row when the checkbox value changes, but nothing works.
Here's what i tried:

```
<script>    
$('input[name="chkConcluida"]').on('change', function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('bg-success', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
</script>
```

table:

```
<div class="container">
<table id="tarefa" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="display:none">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TAR_ID)
        </th>
        <th class="col-sm text-muted" style="width: 10%">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TAR_CONCLUIDA)
        </th>
        <th class="col-sm text-muted" style="width: 72.9%">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TAR_DESCRICAO)
        </th>
        <th class="col-sm text-muted">
            Ações
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
           <tr>
                <td style="display:none">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TAR_ID)
                </td>
                <td class="text-center align-middle">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chkConcluida" id="chkConcluida" onclick="MudarCheckbox(this, @item.TAR_ID)" checked/>
                    @*@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.TAR_CONCLUIDA, new { onclick = "MudarCheckbox(this, " + item.TAR_ID + ") "})*@
                </td>
                <td class="h5 align-middle">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TAR_DESCRICAO)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#editarTarefa" data-tarefa-descricao="@item.TAR_DESCRICAO" data-tarefa-id="@item.TAR_ID">Editar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" href="#removerTarefa" data-tarefa-id="@item.TAR_ID">Remover</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
    }

</table>
```

It's a ASP.NET MVC BOOTSTRAP 4 application.
I've read so many similar questions and nothing worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change background color of a row on checkbox selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828881/how-to-change-background-color-of-a-row-on-checkbox-selection)

Comment: I used the code in that question in my solution but it didn't work till i put it inside "$(document).ready(function(){}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something that works:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[name='chkConcluida']").on('change', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('bg-success', $(this).is(':checked'));
        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('strike', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
})
```

had to put the code inside .ready() now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be your css is wrong. I would suggest trouble shooting as follows:

First, check that the event is firing via `console.debug('fired');` or by calling `alert('fired');`.  If you get nothing after checking the box, it means you aren't attaching the event handler to the right element. Second, check that the css is working by hard coding the class: `<tr class="bg-success">`.  Lastly, I would check you are getting the correct tr element. For this you could put an id on it and print it out: `alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));`

Here is a JSFiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/snLxhd15/4/